# Where does the factor of $\gamma^2$ come from in synchrotron radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, synchrotron-radiation

I've read the derivation for [synchrotron radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) (as derived by Griffiths), so I know *how* to get it given the retarded potentials, etc.

I'm having a hard time with intuition. The derivation in *Radiative Processes in Astrophyscs - Rybicki & Lightman* confuses me, but they do state that in the electrons rest frame, the photon has an increased energy by a factor of $\gamma$ and if you go back to the scattering frame, you get a total factor of $\gamma^2$.

With my intuition, it seems that if you go from the photon's frame to the electron rest frame, you get a factor of $\gamma$, and if you go to the scattering frame you'll get a factor of $1/\gamma$ so they should cancel out.

What am I missing?

Comment: Be careful, photons do not have rest frames according to relativity.  They are always traveling at the local speed of light, no matter from which frame you chose to view the universe.  I do not have my copy of _Rybicki & Lightman_ next to me, but I do recall that the power radiated by accelerating charged particles is not uniform with respect to a background guide magnetic field.  Isn't one direction $\propto$ $\gamma^{2}$ and the other $\propto$ $\gamma^{4}$ (or something similar)?